# Combining/Integrating Swagger & Slate with Spring Microservices

Tags: jenkins, spring-boot, swagger, microservices, slate

I have a set of dockerized microservices (spring boot with jersey application) deployed on EC2 instances. Each service exposes rest apis which i need to create a spec for.

As a first step, i have included swagger-core in all the spring boot apps which generates a .json/.yaml file and serves it on http as a rest resource when the service is up.

I want to use slate to serve the api specification for all the services as a single resource (aggregated from individual json/yaml files) over http/s.

Slate (https://github.com/lord/slate) uses markdown format to serve the static content. 
Library Swagger2Markup can be used to generate the markdown file by aggregating the api specs (json/yaml files) from each services (each have their own json/yaml file generated).

Using this markdown file, i can use slate default middleman to build the static content and serve it over http.

**Question: what can be considered a best practice for seamlessly integrating this process to the jenkins build.**